# Реализация прокси на Python

Tags: python, proxy

Всем привет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении смотреть на решение следующей задачи: есть условная CRM, которая установлена на сервере в AWS Amazon, но руководство не хочет, чтобы доступ к ней был  открытым (то есть доступ к нему прячут во внутреннюю сеть и наружу торчит порт, по которому через прокси надо подключиться таким образом, чтобы содержимое (то есть кабинет этой CRM) был доступен для тех, кто зайдет через прокси. Ну и дальше чтобы можно было работать с этим личным кабинетом как обычно. И этот прокси мне нужно написать на Python, потому что руководство не хочет устанавливать себе какие-то прокси, VPN и тд. Руководство хочет зайти по урлу и попасть сразу в кабинет CRM.

И вот этот прокси мне нужно сделать самостоятельно на Python.

Так вот, подскажите как это реализовать на Python?

Comment: Мб в той CRM будете проверять наличие какого-нибудь заголовка HTTP с каким-то определенным значением? Той же прокси можно было его подставлять. А так, есть модуль из коробки, и пример прокси через него: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4412630/5909792

Comment: Пытаюсь понять вопрос. Вам нужен [обратный прокси](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8)? Зачем писать самому, а не использовать [готовые](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/serving-content-using-fully-managed-reverse-proxy-architecture/) [решения](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/application-load-balancer/) от aws или на худой конец nginx?

Comment: Может и обратный прокси. Я пока не понимаю как решить эту задачу ) Если я мог правильно сформулировать вопрос, это было бы уже почти решением ))) Спасибо за ссылки - буду вникать.

Comment: Вопрос не в том как решить. Вопрос в том "в чем состоит задача". Это не понятно.

Comment: Как мне написать на Python сервис, который будет показывать другую страницу, к которой нужно подключиться через proxy? И с этой страницей нужно еще и взаимодействовать внутри сервиса на Python. Так понятнее?